When is function "run" been called in this python program?
I don't understand this python program, why is the function "run" executed? In the codes segment and the whole program, I don't see the run() been called. Here is the segments of code where the function is declared and the class that contains it which has been executed. The main window is class window2 and the function "run" is declared in it.
###cut off
class PDFWorker(QThread):
    progress_signal = pyqtSignal(int)
    completed_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, files_list, output_path2, start_page, end_page, spinBox_2_value):
        super().__init__()
        self.files_list = files_list
        self.output_path2 = output_path2
        self.start_page = start_page
        self.end_page = end_page
        self.spinBox_2_value = spinBox_2_value

    def run(self):
        print("run4")
        total_pages = 0
        # First, calculate the total number of pages across all PDFs for progress tracking
        for file in self.files_list:
            doc = fitz.open(file)
            total_pages += (len(doc) - self.spinBox_2_value) - self.start_page
            doc.close()

        pages_processed = 0
        # Process each file individually
        for i, file in enumerate(self.files_list):
            doc = fitz.open(file)
            num_pages_in_doc = len(doc)  # Get total pages for this document

            # Calculate the end_page for the current document, ensuring it doesn't exceed the total pages
            end_page = min(num_pages_in_doc - self.spinBox_2_value, self.end_page)

            text = ""
            print(f"Processing {file} from page {self.start_page} to {end_page}")
            
            for page_num in range(self.start_page, end_page):
                page = doc.load_page(page_num)
                pix = page.get_pixmap()
                image = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)
                text += "\n" + pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
                pages_processed += 1

                # Emit progress signal
                progress = int((pages_processed / total_pages) * 100)
                self.progress_signal.emit(progress)

            doc.close()

            # Ensure each output file has a unique name
            output_file = Path(self.output_path2, f"{Path(file).stem}_{i+1}.docx")
            self.create_docx(text, output_file)
            print(f"Created {output_file}")
            print(text)

        # Emit completed signal
        self.completed_signal.emit()



    def create_docx(self, text, file_path):
        doc = Document()
        paragraphs = text.split('\n')
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            doc.add_paragraph(paragraph)
        doc.save(file_path)


class window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window2, self).__init__()
        loadUi(os.path.join(base_path, '2.ui'), self)

        self.action.triggered.connect(self.page1)
        self.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_input_path)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.select_output_folder)

    def start(self):
        print("run1")
        global path2, output_path2

        if path2 == "":
            QMessageBox.critical(self, '', 'E:0014')
            return

        if output_path2 == "":
            QMessageBox.critical(self, '', 'E:0015')
            return

        start_page = self.spinBox.value()
        spinBox_2_value = self.spinBox_2.value()

        if self.radioButton_single.isChecked():
            files_list = [path2]  # Single file
        elif self.radioButton_all.isChecked():
            files_list = find_files(path2, ".pdf")  # Multiple files

        # Open the first file to calculate the total number of pages
        doc = fitz.open(files_list[0])
        end_page = len(doc)  # Set end_page to the total number of pages in the PDF
        doc.close()

        # Create a PDF worker thread and start processing
        print("run2")
        self.pdf_worker = PDFWorker(files_list, output_path2, start_page, end_page, spinBox_2_value)
        self.pdf_worker.progress_signal.connect(self.update_progress_bar)
        self.pdf_worker.completed_signal.connect(self.pdf_processing_completed)
        self.pdf_worker.start()
###cut off


Please add instructions how you execute this code. Also, make sure your code qualifies as a [mcve].

I don't even know what QThread is (pretty sure it is some QT class to help creation of threads in QT apps). But it has to be the one providing a start method (your real question, else, should be "I don't understand where the start method is defined"). That start method probably calls a run method (a "virtual" one to use vocabulary from other language. That is that run of the subclass, here PDFWorker is ran from start from the super-class, QThread)

Have you looked at the documentation for QThread.run?

I think you are right "A QThread object manages one thread of control within the program. QThreads begin executing in run() . By default, run() starts the event loop by calling exec() and runs a Qt event loop inside the thread.", wanna wright the answer? @khelwood

Your class inherits from QThread, and the QThread documentation has this to say about the run() method:

run()
The starting point for the thread. After calling start(), the newly created thread calls this function. The default implementation simply calls exec().
You can reimplement this function to facilitate advanced thread management. Returning from this method will end the execution of the thread.

So whatever is written into the run() will be what happens when the thread runs. You start the thread running by calling start().
